# Retrieve an child value and compare using firebase by javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
    const uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;

var query = firebase.database().ref("/user/").child(user.uid).orderByChild("l1").equalTo("bought ")
     query.on("value", function(snapshot) {
         var lg1=document.getElementById("lg1");
    var lg2=document.getElementById("lg2");
    var blg=document.getElementById("blg");
    lg2.style.display=" none";
    lg1.style.display="block"; 
    blg.style.display="block";
         
     });
```

I am comparing a child data in firebase realtime database and disable enable display using the snapshot function but it's not working I tried and research a lot but I couldn't find a perfect solution.

Any ideas on how to proceed above code?

Here is the screenshot of my firebase realtime database

[image: Firebase realtime database]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase queries work on the list of direct child nodes under the path that you query.

Since your query runs on `/user/$uid`, the nodes the query considers are `email`, `l1`, `points` and `uid`. For each of those it then looks for a child property `l1` and compares the value to what you specified. But none of these four nodes **has** an `l1` property.

If you want to be able to search the child nodes of `/user/$uid` for their `l1` property, you need an extra level in the JSON, which is typically generated by calling `push()` as shown in the documentation on [adding nodes to a list](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#append_to_a_list_of_data). So your JSON would become

```
user: {
  "$uid": {
    "$pushid": { //  new
      email: "...",
      l1: "...",
      points: ...,
      uid: "...",
    }
  }
}
```

With that structure your query will work.